# Animated robot without bones behaves strangely when exported to Unity

Tags: animation, normals, unity

I am trying to export an animated robot for use in Unity. In blender the animation looks fine, but when I open it up in Unity it gets really loose and weird. First I thougt the problem was caused by me not applying the rotation and scale. However, when I did apply it, the copied and mirrored leg and arm of the robot get their normals flipped. When I flipped the normals again it looked fine, but when I went to the next frame of the animation, the mesh suddenly turned very small.

I don't know what is causing this, and I hope some will be able to help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you using an armature at all?

Comment: no, i tried to animate without bones, i also had a problem with exporting animations with bones to unity, i am just curious what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Blender does export object transform animations as .fbx, without using armatures, but you need to export them as a .fbx explicity. Those animations should be done in a NLA window instead of an Action window, and then select the object and export only selected as fbx. The animation will have the length of the scene timeline and will run just fine once inside unity.